# Django -- Allowing Users To Only View Their Own Page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm nearing what I think is the end of development for a Django application I'm building. The key view in this application is a user dashboard to display metrics of some kind. Basically I don't want users to be able to see the dashboards of other users. Right now my view looks like this:

```
@login_required
@permission_required('social_followup.add_list')
def user_dashboard(request, list_id):
    try:
        user_list = models.List.objects.get(pk=list_id)
    except models.List.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'dashboard/view.html', {'user_list': user_list})
```

the url for this view is like this:

```
url(r'u/dashboard/(?P<list_id>\d+)/$', views.user_dashboard, name='user_dashboard'),
```

Right now any logged in user can just change the `list_id` in the URL and access a different dashboard. How can I make it so a user can only view the dashboard for their own list_id, without removing the `list_id` parameter from the URL? I'm pretty new to this part of Django and don't really know which direction to go in.

Comment: What is `list_id`? Is some User's field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pull `request.user` and make sure this List is theirs.

You haven't described your model, but it should be straight forward.

Perhaps you have a user ID stored in your List model? In that case,

```
if not request.user == user_list.user:
    response = http.HttpResponse()
    response.status_code = 403
    return response
```

Comment: I have a join table for lists and users (stupid legacy DB). I think I have a way to adapt this method though, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisClouten, ah yeah, then you'd do the appropriate query. It's pseudo code for "check if user has permission"

Comment: AWESOME. This worked. I just remembered I am doing something similar on another view but I just couldn't think of how to write this one with the lame join table. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I ended up using `raise PermissionDenied`

Answer (score 4):

I solve similiar situations with a reusable mixin. You can add login_required by means of a method decorator for dispatch method or in urlpatterns for the view.

```
class OwnershipMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin providing a dispatch overload that checks object ownership. is_staff and is_supervisor
    are considered object owners as well. This mixin must be loaded before any class based views
    are loaded for example class SomeView(OwnershipMixin, ListView)
    """
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        # we need to manually "wake up" self.request.user which is still a SimpleLazyObject at this point
        # and manually obtain this object's owner information.
        current_user = self.request.user._wrapped if hasattr(self.request.user, '_wrapped') else self.request.user
        object_owner = getattr(self.get_object(), 'author')

        if current_user != object_owner and not current_user.is_superuser and not current_user.is_staff:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(OwnershipMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some information stored about what list or lists a user can access, and then include that in the user_list lookup.  Let's assume the simple case where `List` has a single owner, a foreign key to the `User` model.  That's a many-to-one relationship between lists and users; no list is owned by more than one user, but a user can have multiple lists.  Then you want something like this:

```
try:
    user_list = models.List.objects.get(pk=list_id, owner=request.user)
except models.List.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```

Whether to return 404 or 403 is to some extent a matter of opinion; the definition for 403 says:

> If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4

If you do return a 404, you can use the django shortcut function [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of the explicit try/except - there's nothing wrong with doing it explicitly, but the need is common enough that there's a convenience function to do it.